Action cartoon series from the 90s about underwater civilization
This is a memory from my childhood, I am around 4-5 at the time and only watched one episode, which I believe was the first episode. Thus I don't recall a lot of information.
I would like to identify an action cartoon TV series with the following description:

It revolves around some humans (or maybe mermaids?) living underwater in some sort of community/civilization. I seem to recall some sort of base camp. 
The drawings felt realistic, e.g. the characters did not have disproportionate large heads etc.
I distinctly remember some characters swimming underwater. 
The characters may have been blonde, and there may have been harpoons or some kind of weapons involved. I am almost sure there was at least one male character.
I must have watched it on TV at some point around 1996-1998 and it felt new to me at the time. 

EDIT: - A hunch tells me that these are underwater humanlike creatures and not humans living underwater. 

It is not the Atlantis: The Lost Empire movie from 2001.

It's possible you had seen Sealab 2021 (which ran from 2000-2005 - so it doesn't exactly fit your timeframe), which was a "reboot" of an earlier Sealab 2020.  The former being an Adult Swim comedy, the latter being a more action oriented Hanna Barbera cartoon from 1972.  Sealab 2021 lifted characters and scenes from Sealab 2020.

Good suggestion, although it doesn't feel right. I have a feeling now that the characters were some sort of underwater people and not regular humans living underwater.

if you were 4 or 5 you might have conflated Sealab with "Space Ghost Coast to Coast" in your memory: they ran on a similar schedule and they were only about 15mins each. Space Ghost had non-human characters.

I do not believe this to be the case.

I think your cartoon is Prince of Atlantis:

The Prince of Atlantis was a short lived CGI animated cartoon about a group of underwater creatures who protect the oceans.
In the heart of the ocean, in the mysterious waters of the Bermuda Triangle, is a beautiful city built by the legendary people of Atlantis. Its sole inhabitant is a child, the prince Akata, the last of the Atlanteans. With him in the underwater city lies all the knowledge, technology and the extraordinary powers accumulated by the people for 5000 years. But modern technologies threaten the city: men with sophisticated machinery plumb the depths of the ocean in order to extract its riches. Akata, with the help of the hologram of his master, Shum, must protect the Atlantean heritage, particularly the Blue Ray, this power must never fall into human hands.

Here's an episode in youtube:



The cartoon was released in 1997.

The TV series is almost definitely The Prince Of Atlantis.
There is little information about it online, but it aired in my home country at the correct time and fits my memory.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_of_Atlantis

The Snorks?
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snorks
It's from the 80's but was played in syndication much later.

This is not it. "The drawings felt realistic, e.g. the characters did not have disproportionate large heads etc.". I appreciate the suggestion though.
